# How to continue code on next line (code too long)

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I continue code (record insertion) on the next line?  In the example below I tried using underscore to end a line, then & to begin the next due to suggestions online, but it still doesn't compile.  Any thoughts?

Code Line:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO AIP&BOP (PlanTitle, FileLocation, YearsofData, AnnualImprovedCML, AIP1, AIP1BOP1, AIP2, AIP1BOP2, AIP3, AIP1BOP3, AIP4, AIP1BOP4, AIP5, AIP1BOP5, AIP6, AIP1BOP6, AIP7, AIP1BOP7, AIP8, AIP1BOP8, AIP9, AIP1BOP9, AIP10, AIP1BOP10, AIP11, AIP1BOP11, AIP12, AIP1BOP12, AIP13, AIP1BOP13, AIP14, AIP1BOP14, AIP15, AIP1BOP15, AIP16, AIP1BOP16, AIP17, AIP1BOP17, AIP18, AIP1BOP18, AIP19, AIP1BOP19, AIP20, AIP1BOP20, AIP21, AIP1BOP21, AIP22, AIP1BOP22, AIP23, AIP1BOP23, AIP24, AIP1BOP24) Values ('" & RWPSheetvalues(71) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(72) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(73) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(74) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(1) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(2) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(3) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(4) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(5) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(6) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(7) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(8) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(9) & "', _
& '" & RWPSheetvalues(10) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(11) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(12) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(13) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(14) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(15) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(16) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(17) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(18) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(19) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(20) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(21) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(22) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(23) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(24) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(25) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(26) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(27) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(28) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(29) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(30) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(31) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(32) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(33) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(34) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(35) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(36) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(37) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(38) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(39) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(40) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(41) & "', _
& '" & RWPSheetvalues(42) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(43) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(44) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(45) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(46) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(47) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(48) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(49) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(50) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(51) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(52) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(53) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(54) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(55) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(56) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(57) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(58) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(59) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(60) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(61) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(62) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(63) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(64) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(65) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(66) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(67) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(68) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(69) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(70) & "')"
```

Comment: BTW,I am just trying to insert all of the info for one single  record into a table at the same time.  If there is a better way, that would be useful as well...

Comment: Please do remember that there is a limit of 25 lines. You should use templates or like others mentiones record set for various other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert it one by one using loop either create nested array with records pass it to a function which insert it one by one using loop.

Answer (score 0):

Always have a "finished" string on each line:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO AIP&BOP (PlanTitle, FileLocation, YearsofData, AnnualImprovedCML, AIP1, AIP1BOP1, AIP2, AIP1BOP2, AIP3, AIP1BOP3, AIP4, AIP1BOP4, AIP5, AIP1BOP5, AIP6, AIP1BOP6, AIP7, AIP1BOP7, AIP8, AIP1BOP8, AIP9, AIP1BOP9, AIP10, AIP1BOP10, AIP11, AIP1BOP11, AIP12, AIP1BOP12, AIP13, AIP1BOP13, AIP14, AIP1BOP14, AIP15, AIP1BOP15, AIP16, AIP1BOP16, AIP17, AIP1BOP17, AIP18, AIP1BOP18, AIP19, AIP1BOP19, AIP20, AIP1BOP20, AIP21, AIP1BOP21, AIP22, AIP1BOP22, AIP23, AIP1BOP23, AIP24, AIP1BOP24) Values ('" & RWPSheetvalues(71) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(72) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(73) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(74) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(1) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(2) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(3) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(4) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(5) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(6) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(7) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(8) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(9) & "'," _ &
"'" & RWPSheetvalues(10) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(11) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(12) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(13) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(14) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(15) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(16) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(17) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(18) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(19) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(20) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(21) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(22) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(23) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(24) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(25) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(26) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(27) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(28) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(29) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(30) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(31) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(32) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(33) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(34) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(35) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(36) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(37) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(38) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(39) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(40) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(41) & "'," _ &
"'" & RWPSheetvalues(42) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(43) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(44) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(45) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(46) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(47) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(48) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(49) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(50) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(51) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(52) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(53) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(54) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(55) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(56) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(57) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(58) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(59) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(60) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(61) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(62) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(63) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(64) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(65) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(66) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(67) & "', '" & RWPSheetvalues(68) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(69) & "','" & RWPSheetvalues(70) & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a nightmare to maintain. To set so many columns, using a recordset is better readable.

It also prevents SQL injection and problems with data formatting (e.g. date fields).

```vb
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AIP&BOP")
With RS
    .AddNew
    !PlanTitle = RWPSheetvalues(71)
    !FileLocation = RWPSheetvalues(72)
    !YearsofData = RWPSheetvalues(73)
    ' etc. ........
    .Update
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *DAO* to make it a lot cleaner:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From [AIP&BOP]")
rs.AddNew
    rs!PlanTitle.Value = RWPSheetvalues(10) 
    rs!FileLocation.Value = RWPSheetvalues(11) 
    ' etc.
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ended your line this way: `"','" & RWPSheetvalues(9) & "', _`, putting the underscore **inside** the String. The interpreter interpreted the underscore as a character in the String, rather than a line connector, and the String to be endless. The String in the next line is interpreted as not started.
Just end the string a the end of the line:
`"','" & RWPSheetvalues(9) & "', " _`
and begin a concatenated String at the beginning of the next line:
`& "'" & RWPSheetvalues(10)`

I would also highly recommend you add more underscores, and make the code more readable.